# Need to switch accounts in outlook using python for sending email using other account

Tags: python, outlook, outlook-redemption

I have the following code

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'madanraj.c@sss.com;
mail.Subject = 'Daily Backlog'
mail.Send()
```

I have two accounts in outlook and i installed redemption too, but struck how to switch account

i saw vb code and i cant convert to python code

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set Accounts = Session.Accounts
for each Account in Accounts
  Debug.Print Account.Name
next
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` property.

Comment: What part are having problems with? Have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount ?

Comment: I dono the syntax in python for using that property

Comment: Need to select the other account.. ab@xyz.com , bc@ttt.com . Need to mail from bc@ttt.com where ab@xyz.com is default one..

Comment: You retrieve the account you need from the Application.Session.Accounts collection and assign it to the MailItem.SendUsingAccount  property. Which part are you having problems with? What have you tried?

Comment: outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')

mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "hello5@xyz.com"
mail.To = 'madanraj.c@abcd.com'

mail.Subject = 'Daily Backlog'

mail.Body = 'This Mail is Sent by Python'

mail.HTMLBody = '<h2>HTML Message body</h2>' #this field is optional


#attachment  = "C:\\Users\madanraj.c\Downloads\Report.csv"
#mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)


mail.Send()

Comment: Are you sending on behalf of another Exchange account? Or seining using another POP3/SMTP account?

Comment: Sending with other domain, other SMTP account.

Comment: Then you need to set the SendUsingAccount property. What have you tried?

Comment: I didn try with sendusing account property.. where and how to start with python as i dono the VBA code..

Comment: mail.SendUsingAccount = "hello5@abcd.com", tried this but it sends from madanraj.c@abcd.com only..

Comment: SendUsingAccount  takes an Account object, not a string. I don't know how I can make it any easier short of actually writing the code for you - "you retrieve the account you need from the Application.Session.Accounts collection and assign it to the MailItem.SendUsingAccount property"

Comment: <COMObject <unknown>> this is i get when i use appliaction . session. accouny

Comment: Loop through the accounts in the Application.Session.Acounts collection to retrieve the account you want based on whatever criteria that makes sense in your case.

Comment: If you don't want to look at the docs (link in my first comment), install OutlookSpy and take a look at the live objects.

Comment: for abcin Application.Session.Accounts:
    print(abcin)

Comment: Im not getting my second account here

Comment: for (abc in Application.Session.Accounts) { print(abc.Name); }

Comment: If the answer answers your question, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this comes late but I think people might find it useful. This is how I've managed to select an e-mail address to send from, as I had multiple addresses in outlook.

```
import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application') 

mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.Subject = "Test subject"
mail.To = "yourrecipient@gmail.com"

# If you want to set which address the e-mail is sent from. 
# The e-mail needs to be part of your outlook account.
From = None
for myEmailAddress in outlook.Session.Accounts:
    if "gmail.com" in str(myEmailAddress):
        From = myEmailAddress
        break

if From != None:
    # This line basically calls the "mail.SendUsingAccount = xyz@email.com" outlook VBA command
    mail._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, From))

mail.Send()
```

Answer (score 0):

mail.*oleobj*.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, From)) - This command threw the below  exception :-

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The item has been moved or deleted.', None, 0, -2147221238), None)

Please look into it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32521668)