# Python: Using another mailbox in sending emails

Tags: python, outlook, send, inbox

I have three mailboxes on my Outlook. How can I use my other mailbox in sending email via Python? The below script currently uses my main inbox = jgliban@ims.com. How can I use my other mailbox (jgliban@iqvia.com) in sending the email on the script?

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.GetInspector
mail.To = 'jgliban@ims.com'
mail.CC = 'jgliban@ims.com'
mail.Subject = 'Test Email'
index = mail.HTMLbody.find('>', mail.HTMLbody.find('<body')) 
mail.HTMLbody = mail.HTMLbody[:index + 1] + 'Hello,<br> <br>This is a test email<br><br>Many thanks and kind regards. ' + mail.HTMLbody[index + 1:]
mail.Send()
```

Comment: By changing `mail.To` value to `jgliban@iqvia.com` or whatever?

Comment: The mail.To is the recipient of the Test Email. Above, if run in Python, will use my main inbox = jgliban@ims.com to send a Test Email to my main inbox = jgliban@ims.com. I want to use another inbox = jgliban@iqvia.com to send the above Test Email to my main inbox = jgliban@ims.com.

Comment: You mean your *account*, then I guess. As you expressed as *mailbox*, it sounds like the `To` address. In short, you want to change the `From` address, right?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to change the From address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is an Exchange mailbox, set the `MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName` property to the name of the delegate mailbox.

Answer (score 2):

I was about to suggest SMTP, but since you are already connecting to the outlook application using win32, maybe this will help?

[Need to switch accounts in outlook using python for sending email using other account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52202852/need-to-switch-accounts-in-outlook-using-python-for-sending-email-using-other-ac)

From the answer in the link:

> Set MailItem.SendUsingAccount property.

Edit: Umm. It is given in the comments:

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
for acc in outlook.Session.Accounts:
    print (acc)
    if str(acc) == 'jgliban@iqvia.com':
        mail.SendUsingAccount = acc
```

Comment: Hi. How do I go about doing that? Sorry. I'm practically new to Python.

Comment: Thank you. It's still sending using my other account though. I've just added the script you gave as is on my script.